# HTML Select then fill input boxes

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi i am using HTML and PHP to create an Update page for my msql db, i currently have the this for selecting a record.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `servers`") or die (mysql_error());

while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    echo "<option value='".$temp['Server_ID']."'>".$temp['Server_ID']." - ".$temp['Server_name']."</option>";
}
```

what i would like is when i select a record from this select box, for it to fill the rest of the records details in the input boxes i have. I am very new to PHP so have tried this but it does not work just comes up blank.

```
while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `servers`") or die (mysql_error());
    echo "Server Name : <input type='text' name='".'servername'."' value='".$temp['Server_name']."'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='".'location'."' value='".$temp['Location']."'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='".'macaddress'."' value='".$temp['MAC_Address']."'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='".'portnumber'."' value='".$temp['Port_Number']."'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='".'ipaddress'."' value='".$temp['IP_Address']."'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='".'operatingsystem'."' value='".$temp['Operating_System']."'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='".'admin'."' value='".$temp['Administrator']."'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='".'contactno'."' value='".$temp['Contact_Number']."'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='".'email'."' value='".$temp['Email']."'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='".'secondcontact'."' value='".$temp['Second_Contact']."'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='".'secondcontactno'."' value='".$temp['Second_Contact_Number']."'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='".'comment'."' value='".$temp['Comments']."'>";
}
```

i would prefer to not use jquery or ajax is possible.
Thanks Guys.

Comment: If you want to show them up when an option from the select box is selected, then you need Ajax. Another way would be a form redirecting you to the same page and checking if the $_POST[] is filled up and then make the query that will fill the inputs

Answer (score 0):

Without JS/jQuery at all this is not really possible in a comfortable way. With minimal JS it would look something like this:

1. create a form
2. use an onchange event to submit the form

   ```
   <select onchange="this.form.submit()">
   ...
   </select>
   ```
3. Use the $_POST variable to create your SQL in PHP and to echo your inputs

Answer (score 0):

Without Javascript or Jquery, you won't be able to show the details from a record from your database in the same moment you change the value.

If you reject this way, you can do it, of course, but you will need to submit a form.

1. Create a form pointing at the same page. Insert here a `<select>` and the submit button.
2. At the top of the page, (I would go with an array) create an array with keys and empty values. Then, check if is set `$_POST['select']` and then create the query. Insert in the array the values you need.
3. In the values from the `<input>`'s echo the variables from the array. If you submitted the select, you will have your variables, if not, values will be empty.